# I am getting import errors when trying to import my database into my own module

Tags: python, flask, import, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a module called crop.py in my flask application. Everything works great until I want to import database parts from models.py. I'm guessing it has something to do with initializing the module into the app and then trying to import models into it, but I'm not sure.

Here is the error:
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing 'test', an ImportError was raised.

Here is my basic app construction.
-app
models.py
crop.py

crop.py

```
from app import current_app 
from flask import url_for, Markup
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from uuid import uuid4
import os
#Adding these below causes an importerror------------------------------------
#from app import db
#from app.models import Upload

class _Avatars(object):
    #code here

class Avatars(object):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    #code here
```

__init.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, current_app _l
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from redis import Redis
import rq
from config import Config
#This is my module-----------------------------------------------------
from .crop import Avatars

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
avatars = Avatars()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)    

    db.init_app(app)
    avatars.init_app(app)
```

Comment: Taking a few hours to work through the Flask Mega Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world") will pay off. There's text if you favor reading, and videos if you favor watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is causing a circular import error, since you're importing your crop model in your __init.py file and you're import db from __init.py into crop model file. Python does not allow this kind of scenario. Either you'll have to define your DB connections elsewhere in a separate file or add them manually everywhere you need to use the DB.

Comment: That was what it was. I ended up killing the module approach and I embedded the funcitons into the python file I needed directly.